# unsigned int is not uint32_t when compile to cortex-m0 -- possible C compiler flag issue

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, uint32

I've needed to port a project to run with Eclipse with its own Makefile. I have modified its makefile, and i guess the error is connected to it or a compiler flag.

Host: Virtualbox Win 8,x64,
target device: nrf51822 which is arm cortex-m0.
I use gnu arm cross compiler 4.8.4 (GNU Tools ARM Embedded)

Compile shows the following error/warning message:

```
src/main.c:173:4: error: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'uint32_t' [-Werror=format=]
```

I don't understand it. **uint32_t** is **unsigned int** in this case. I've included stdint.h.

I compile sources with the following flags:

```
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs --std=gnu11 -funsigned-char -DNRF51 -DDEBUG_NRF_USER -DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD -DBOARD_PCA10000 -DNRF51822_QFAA_CA
CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=soft
```

Does not -mcpu=cortex-m0 specifies the size of the integer? stdint.h pre-processor macros should generate "typedef unsigned int __uint32_t;". Eclipse shows it that this line is compiled, but i do not know wether to trust it because external makefile is used with its own compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think it's undefined to use `%u` for `uint32_t`, even if it has the same size as `unsigned int`. So the warning might be justified somehow (although it may be safe to ignore it).

Comment: Suggest `"%" PRIu32` instead of `"%u"`.

Comment: @mafso No, that's not it, because a) that's not undefined and b) typedefs are just aliases, so if `uint32_t` really is typedefed as `unsigned int` then they are exactly the same type. I suspect that the OP is mistaken and `unsigned int` isn't 32 bits. Printing `sizeof(unsigned int)` would confirm.

Comment: @Jim Balter  Printing `sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT` would confirm even more.

Comment: Posting code main.c:173 may help.

Comment: @JimBalter: Ad a) Do you have a source for that? `sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(unsigned)` doesn't imply that they are aliases, they both could be typedefs to some built-in type, as I read the standard, and they both could be different types (similar to how `char` may be like `signed char` but a different type). I'm curious if such a warning would be justified even on systems with `sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(unsigned int)`...

Comment: @mafso No, I had it mixed up with the fact that you can pass a positive int to %u , but that's because `int` and `unsigned int` are "corresponding types". The standard does indeed allow multiple integer types of the same size that aren't compatible, although I don't think there is any such thing in existence and it seems like a bad idea. "similar to how char may be like signed char but a different type" -- but the standard says "The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char" so passing any of them to %c is safe.

Comment: I have managed to run code: int k = sizeof(int); //is 4
  k = sizeof(unsigned int); //is 4
  k = sizeof(uint32_t);     //is 4
  k = sizeof(long int);//is 4
  k = sizeof(short int);//is 2

Comment: I have a couple of warning like the posted one, but the code is the following: sprintf(buf,"Error: %u %u %s\n\r",error_code, line_num,p_file_name); //which are uint32_t, uint32_t and  const uint8_t *

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`uint32_t` is a typedef (an alias) for *some* predefined unsigned integer type. That type is guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits wide, with no padding bits. You cannot safely assume that it's an alias for any particular type. It could plausibly be either `unsigned int` or `unsigned long int`. (Less plausibly, it could be `unsigned char` or `unsigned short` on an unusual system, or it could be an *extended integer type*; it cannot be `unsigned long long`, which is at least 64 bits wide.)

If your implementation has more than one 32-bit unsigned integer type with no padding bits, `uint32_t` could be any of them, at the whim of the implementer.

Printing a `uint32_t` value with `"%u"` is non-portable. You can get away with it if your implementation happens to define `uint32_t` as `unsigned int` (yours apparently does not). You can *probably* get away with it if `unsigned int` happens to be 32 bits.

The correct format for `uint32_t` is defined as a macro in `<inttypes.h>`:

```
uint32_t x = 42;
printf("x = %" PRIu32 "\n", x);
```

(`PRIu32` expands to a string literal; this takes advantage of the fact that adjacent string literals are concatenated.)

An easier way is to convert the value to a known type:

```
uint32_t x = 42;
printf("x = %ju\n", (intmax_t)x);
```

or perhaps:

```
uint32_t x = 42;
printf("x = %llu\n", (unsigned long long)x);
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Actually i have managed to find that in _default_types.h (included from stdint.h) typedef __UINT32_TYPE__ __uint32_t;
and it looks like that this macro is set by the compiler.

Comment: How PRIu32 can be used? Compiler tells for:
   printf("x = %" PRIu32 "\n", (uint32_t)3);
src/main.c:174:19: error: expected ')' before 'PRIu32'

Comment: @Dati: You need `#include <inttypes.h>`